# How UE checks the health for building of the Android platform?

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-development-kit

I’ve got `Platform Android is not a valid platform to build. Check that the SDK is installed properly` error. The question is, where is the code which checks the health of Android building environment and initialize it?

By the available log file, seems like from UE point of view not all components are installed properly. I checked all similar questions and all available installation guides, checked and compared paths. Nothing helped. Also one week ago it worked pretty fine, and I’m sure I didn’t touch Android SDK myself. Unfortunately the log gives no clue what exactly is wrong.

So I gave up and decided to dig the corresponding piece of code. Therefore there are two questions:

- Where is the Android building defined?
- Is there a way to get more verbose logs? I’d like to see what files where checked or what commands were run and why it was detected as incomplete?

I’d appreciate any clues.

Answer (score 0):

For faster repro, try:

```
Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool/UnrealBuildTool.exe -Mode=ValidatePlatforms -AllPlatforms
```

It should show `Android VALID`.

(See: `Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/Modes/ValidatePlatformsMode.cs`)

Then double check your `NDKROOT` environment variable. It should point to something like:

```
%LocalAppData%\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393
```

The verification comes from `Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/Platform/Android/AndroidPlatformSDK.cs::GetInstalledSDKVersion()`